# POSTGRESQL. ERROR con restricción CHECK que satisfaga una condición

Tags: postgresql

Necesito añadir una restricción (check) a una columna siempre y cuando los valores de otra sean igual a un texto específico. Es decir, necesito poner una restricción a una columna siempre y cuando se satisfaga una condición. O dicho de otra manera, necesito hacer una restricción solo a ciertos registros.

¿Puedo utilizar un WHERE en un check? ¿o como puedo hacerlo?

Muchas gracias.

---

No me refiero al crear la tabla.
Tengo que crear la siguiente restricción:

**Se ha de añadir una restricción de tabla, de forma que la nueva columna trans_lo permita almacenar, además del valor por defecto, otros valores diferentes que comiencen por ‘4800’ para aquellos tipos de transacción A554.**

Es decir, añadir una restricción cuando el tipo de transacción es igual a A554.

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Esto te respondo suponiendo que te refieres a esta forma al crear una tabla, podrias probar

```
columna1 text CHECK (columna2 = 'PRUEBA')
```

por ahora no ando en mi equipo para realizar pruebas pero podrias verificarlo ten encuenta que si el texto esta en minuscula no sera igual.
Podrias formular tu pregunta usando algun ejemplo de codigo como lo estas realizando